# Naming buffer exports dynamically in tmux

Tags: tmux

I've grown tired of trying to get tmux scollback working with iTerm2 and my keymapping of choice.  Having realized that I can dump buffers into text files, I find that this is no longer necessary, or even particularly desirable.  Currently my binding to achieve this effect is as follows:

```
bind B capture-pane -S -999000 \; save-buffer ~/.tmux/buffers/filename
```

Of course, this arrangement leads to me clobbering `filename` every time I dump a buffer.  What would be much niftier is a buffer-naming format of `$PANE-NAME_YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS` (where the date and time are current on-dump).

I've looked through `tmux(1)` and while it notes some variables that are available, including times related to client activity, I was unable to successfully expand them into the filename in my `.tmux.conf`, and I don't think that this is really what I'm looking for anyway.

I'm fairly certain that I'm missing something obvious, but at this point I've spent so much time looking for it that I'm not sure I'd recognize it if I *did* see it.  Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making `tmux` run these as shell commands, with the `run-shell` (aliased to `run`) instruction and some additional quoting:

```
bind B run "tmux capture-pane -S -999000; tmux save-buffer ~/.tmux/buffers/\"$(date +%d%m%y)\""
```

This will save your buffer output as `~/.tmux/buffers/240115`. You can obviously customize the `date` command to deliver the degree of granularity that you require.

Regarding using the `pane_title`: if you read the FORMATS section of the man page, it states:

> Certain commands accept the -F flag with a format argument.

Unfortunately, `save-buffer` is not one of those commands.

You can, however, hack around it using the `list-panes` command to retrieve the current window name:

```
bind B run "tmux capture-pane -S -999000; tmux save-buffer ~/.tmux/buffers/\"$(tmux list-panes -F '#{window_name}')\"_\"$(date +%d%m%y)\""
```

which will return, for example,: `~/.tmux/buffers/zsh_240115`.

Comment: This worked beautifully, and I'm happy to accept this answer.  Can you please address the extraction/expansion of $PANE-NAME before I do so, if possible?

Comment: @tripleplus Updated...

Comment: This solution raised another, similar [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180852/chaining-tmux-configuration-commands-using-the-run-command), which I'm hopeful that you can help me with as well.  Thanks again for this fix.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works, and has been part of my `.tmux.conf` key bindings for a while now. Just curious, the `capture-pane` will create a new entry in the tmux buffer list and clutters my buffer list because this is an entire screen capture. I was trying to delete it from the buffer list (after the capture pane has been save into the file, of course). But unable to auto-delete it from tmux buffer list. I named it as `lastcapture` such that I can chain a next tmux command to delete this named buffer, but didn't work in this chain. I can, of course, delete the buffer on a separate key binding.