# Chaining tmux configuration commands using the "run" command

Tags: tmux

In a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180781/naming-buffer-exports-dynamically-in-tmux), I asked how to export dynamically-named buffers from tmux.  The accepted answer worked perfectly.  Having implemented this solution, I attempted to extend it to provide some user feedback, and (eventually) clear the buffer once it had been exported.  This did not end up working as I expected it to.

My original (post-fix) working tmux binding, with only minor changes from the suggested code:

```
bind B run "tmux capture-pane -S -999000 ; tmux save-buffer ~/.tmux/buffers/\"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)\""
```

My first attempt to extend it, by adding an status bar announcement that the operation was successful:

```
bind B run "tmux capture-pane -S -999000 ; tmux save-buffer ~/.tmux/buffers/\"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)\" ; tmux display "SCROLLBACK BUFFER CAPTURED""
```

This produced the following error message:

```
…/.tmux.conf:63: usage: run-shell [-b] [-t target-pane] shell-command
```

I don’t understand why the last semicolon-delimited command is breaking stuff, given that the `tmux` prefix is present and the closing double quote has been moved to the end of the string.  FWIW, I'm running iTerm2 on OS X 10.10.1 ("Yosemite").

How do I arbitrarily chain tmux configuration commands using the `run` syntax demonstrated above?

Comment: Quoting: after the `;` append: `tmux display-message 'Buffer captured'"` or escape the double quotes (as per the `date` command)...

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how I missed that (escaping the quotes) - that was definitely my problem.  Do you want to submit a formal answer to my question so I can accept it?

Comment: No: I have voted to close on the grounds that it was, essentially, a typo...